# I have an issue with converting numbers to words

Tags: c#, string, numbers

so i'm having an issue with the decimal part where the number that you input in the console is for example 0,02 and it gives in words only 2 out of the 3 characters (skips the second 0) i tried many solutions including just doing an if() where i have a double mn = 0.9 but i found out that the if works only to 0 it accepts the variable that i made but its seems like it doesnt understands it. If you have any idea how i can fix this glad to hear

P.S I've attached the whole code on the other paragraph. Thank you!

what i want to happen Input 0,02 ---> output zero point zero two
what is happening Input - 0,02 ----> output zero point 2

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        // OT VIKTOR BOTKOV 304sr
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Въведете число.....:");
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            number = ConvertAmount(double.Parse(number));
            Console.WriteLine("Числото изписано в думи е : \n{0}", number);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }   
    private static String[] units = { "нула", "едно", "две", "три",
    "четири", "пет", "шест", "седем", "осем", "девет", "десет", "единайсет",
    "дванайсет", "тринайсет", "четиринайсет", "петнайсет", "шеснайсет",
    "седемнайсет", "осемнайсет", "деветнайсет" };
    private static String[] tens = { "", "", "двайсет", "трийсет", "четиресет",
    "педесет", "шейсет", "седемдесет", "осемдесет", "деведесет" };
    private static String[] hundreds = {"","сто", "двеста", "триста","четиристотин",
    "петстотин", "шестстотин", "седемстотин", "осемстотин", "деветстотин" };
    private static String[] thousands = {"","хиляда","две хиялди", "три хиляди","четири хиляди",
    "пет хиляди", "шест хиляди", "седем хиляди", "осем хиляди", "девет хиляди" };
    private static String[] unitsс = { "нула ", "един", "два", };

    


    public static String ConvertAmount(double amount)
    {
        try
        {
            double mn = 0.09;
            Int64 amount_int = (Int64)amount;
            Int64 amount_dec = (Int64)Math.Round((Decimal)(amount - (double)(amount_int)) * 100);
            if (amount_dec == 0)
            {
                return Convert(amount_int) + " лв.";
            }
            else if (amount_int <= mn)
            {
                return Convert(amount_int) + " Цяло и " + " Нула " + Convert(amount_dec) + " ст.";
            }
            else
            {
                return Convert(amount_int) + " лв. и " + Convert(amount_dec) + " ст.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return "";
        
    }

    public static String Convert(Int64 i)
    {
    Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
        
      
        if (i<=2)
        {
            return unitsс[i];
           
        }
        if (i < 20)
        {
            return units[i];
        }
        if (i < 100)
        {
            return tens[i / 10] + ((i % 10 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 10) : "");
        }
        if (i < 1000)
        {
            return hundreds[i / 100] + ((i % 100 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 100) : "");
        }
        if (i < 100000)
        {
            return Convert(i / 1000) + " Хиляди "
                        + ((i % 1000 > 0) ? "  " + Convert(i % 1000) : "");
        }
        else if (i < 1000000)
        {
            return Convert(i / 10000) + " Хиляди "
                    + ((i % 10000 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 10000) : "");
        }
        if (i < 10000000)
        {
            return Convert(i / 1000000) + " Милиона "
                    + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? " " + Convert(i % 1000000) : "");
        }
        if (i < 100000000)
        {
            return Convert(i / 1000000) + " Милиона "
                    + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? " и " + Convert(i % 1000000) : "");
        }
        if (i < 1000000000)
        {
            return Convert(i / 1000000) + " Милиона "
                    + ((i % 1000000 > 0) ? "  " + Convert(i % 1000000) : "");
        }
        if (i < 10000000000)
        {
            return Convert(i / 1000000000) + " Милиaрда "
                    + ((i % 1000000000 > 0) ? "  " + Convert(i % 1000000000) : "");
        }
        return Convert(i / 1000000000000) + "  "
                    + ((i % 1000000000000 > 0) ? " " + Convert(i % 10000000000000) : "");

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You *do* know that C#, C++ and C are three ***very*** different languages? Please don't spam tags.

Comment: `if (amount_int <= mn)` Try changing `amount_int` to `amount` (the floating point value.) That should work for `0.02`, but you'll have to do some more work for `1.02` and on upward.

Comment: Yeah ,thank you now it works for 0.0n

Comment: Also sorry for the many tags I removed them

Comment: Fe203 can you help with the 1.02 .., etc. ?

Comment: Pay attention to the decimal separator. Some cultures use dot (`.`) some use comma (`,`) You will need to use the right one for your culture. Or Specify the desired culture when parsing.

Comment: It's been a long day. More or less, `int pennies = (int)((amount * 100.00))%100;` Then you can compare `if( pennies < 10 ) addExtraZero; else easyValue;` Kinda like that...

Comment: Ty Fe2O3 ill try that and also JonasH i use the right ones. Thank you!

Comment: Fe2O3 update on the sit , everything is working thank you so much !

Comment: Funny! I don't know the language being printed, and I have never ever worked with C#... I guess it's a bit like knowing Latin to help one figure out a lot of unknown European languages... Cheers... Glad you got it going... :-)

Comment: Language is Bulgarian (Slavic alphabet).. :DD

Comment: Hey so i have one more question about the same program , how can i make when the number is exactly 0,01 the console to print instead of one - first and to keep 1,00 as one